# Longest positive sum substring

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering how could I get the longest positive-sum subsequence in a sequence:

For example I have -6 3 -4 4 -5, so the longest positive subsequence is 3 -4 4. In fact the sum is positive (3), and we couldn't add -6 neither -5 or it would have become negative.

It could be easily solvable in O(N^2), I think could exist something much more faster, like in O(NlogN)

Do you have any idea?

EDIT: the order must be preserved, and you can skip any number from the substring

EDIT2: I'm sorry if I caused confusion using the term "sebsequence", as @beaker pointed out I meant substring

Comment: In what language? You have this merely tagged "algorithm" -- what do you want? Pseudocode?

Comment: Pseudocode and c++ are perfectly fine

Comment: Can you elaborate on positive-sum sequence? You mean the longest sequence of positive integers presumably? But if so what's 3 -4 4?

Comment: @WindsorAndy The longest subsequence of any length whose sum of all its members is greater than zero, I presume.

Comment: Must the order of the subsequence be preserved? If you sort the numbers first you can sum them until it drops below zero and return the list of numbers you got up to just before that point, but they would not be in the order of the original sequence that way. (I presume the answer is yes -- just clarifying you're not looking for a subset.)

Comment: preserved, and the subsequence must me continuous

Comment: Is the length of the initial sequence known at the start?

Comment: you have N elements, and you know the elements

Comment: Why isn't the maximum positive subsequence in the original array 3, 4 for a total of 7?

Comment: As described, you can't skip numbers, or you could easily sum all the positive number.

Comment: @rodi all positive numbers plus as many negative numbers as possible without dropping below zero.

Comment: @genisage during the process you can drop below zero, but the final subsequence can't. Just to be clear, this is not the problem of the largest sum subsequence

Comment: I'm thinking out loud here and this feels v low tech.. but is it worth first collapsing all adjacent positive numbers into a single positive value (keeping a reference to the original array start/finish).  The longest +ve sequence will be centred on one of those

Comment: @rodi `As described, you can't skip numbers...`. This contradicts your edit in the question. It also contradicts the use of `subsequence` in the title and question since, by definition, a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) can skip elements.

Answer (score 4):

`O(n)` space and time solution, will start with the code (sorry, Java ;-) and try to explain it later:

```java
  public static int[] longestSubarray(int[] inp) {
    // array containing prefix sums up to a certain index i
    int[] p = new int[inp.length];
    p[0] = inp[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inp.length; i++) {
      p[i] = p[i - 1] + inp[i];
    }

    // array Q from the description below
    int[] q = new int[inp.length];
    q[inp.length - 1] = p[inp.length - 1];
    for (int i = inp.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      q[i] = Math.max(q[i + 1], p[i]);
    }

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int maxLen = 0;
    int curr;
    int[] res = new int[] {-1,-1};
    while (b < inp.length) {
      curr = a > 0 ? q[b] - p[a-1] : q[b];
      if (curr >= 0) {
        if(b-a > maxLen) {
          maxLen = b-a;
          res = new int[] {a,b};
        }
        b++;
      } else {
        a++;
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
```

- we are operating on input array `A` of size `n`
- Let's define array `P` as the array containing the prefix sum until index `i` so `P[i] = sum(0,i)` where `i = 0,1,...,n-1'
- let's notice that if `u < v` and `P[u] <= P[v]` then `u` will never be our ending point
- because of the above we can define an array `Q` which has `Q[n-1] = P[n-1]` and `Q[i] = max(P[i], Q[i+1])`
- now let's consider `M_{a,b}` which shows us the maximum sum subarray starting at `a` and ending at `b` or beyond. We know that `M_{0,b} = Q[b]` and that `M_{a,b} = Q[b] - P[a-1]`
- with the above information we can now initialise our `a, b = 0` and start moving them. If the current value of `M` is bigger or equal to 0 then we know we will find (or already found) a subarray with sum >= 0, we then just need to compare `b-a` with the previously found length. Otherwise there's no subarray that starts at `a` and adheres to our constraints so we need to increment `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a naive implementation and then improve it.

We move from the left to the right calculating partial sums and for each position we find the most-left partial sum such as the current partial sum is greater than that.

```
input a
int partialSums[len(a)]
for i in range(len(a)):
    partialSums[i] = (i == 0 ? 0 : partialSums[i - 1]) + a[i]
    if partialSums[i] > 0:
        answer = max(answer, i + 1)
    else:
        for j in range(i):
            if partialSums[i] - partialSums[j] > 0:
                answer = max(answer, i - j)
                break
```

This is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Now the part of finding the left-most "good" sum could be actually maintained via [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), where each node would be represented as a pair `(partial sum, index)` with a comparison by `partial sum`. Also each node should support a special field `min` that would be the minimum of `indices` in this subtree.

Now instead of the straightforward search of an appropriate partial sum we could descend the BST using the current partial sum as a key following the next three rules (assuming `C` is the current node, `L` and `R` are the roots of the left and the right subtrees respectively):

1. Maintain the current minimal index of "good" partial sums found in `curMin`, initially `+∞`.
2. If `C.partial_sum` is "good" then update `curMin` with `C.index`.
3. If we go to `R` then update `curMin` with `L.min`.

And then update the `answer` with `i - curMin`, also add the current partial sum to the BST.

That would give us O(n * log n).

Answer (score 1):

We can easily have a O(n log n) solution for longest **subsequence**.

- First, sort the array, remember their indexes.
- Pick all the largest numbers, stop when their sum are negative, and you have your answer.
- Recover their original order.

Pseudo code

```
  sort(data);
  int length = 0;
  long sum = 0;
  boolean[] result = new boolean[n];
  for(int i = n ; i >= 1; i--){
      if(sum + data[i] <= 0)
         break;
      sum += data[i];
      result[data[i].index] = true;
      length++;
  }
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      if(result[i])
        print i;
```

So, rather than waiting, I will propose a O(n log n) solution for longest positive **substring**.

- First, we create an array `prefix` which is the prefix sum of the array.
- Second, we using binary search to look for the longest length that has positive sum

Pseudocode

```
  int[]prefix = new int[n];
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      prefix[i] = data[i];
      if(i - 1 >= 1)
        prefix[i] += prefix[i - 1]; 
  int min = 0;
  int max = n;
  int result = 0;
  while(min <= max){
       int mid = (min + max)/2;
       boolean ok = false;
       for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
           if(i > mid && pre[i] - pre[i - mid] > 0){//How we can find sum of segment with mid length, and end at index i
                ok = true;
                break;
           }
      }
      if(ok){
         result = max(result, mid)
         min = mid + 1;
      }else{
         max = mid - 1;
      }
  }
```

Ok, so the above algorithm is wrong, as pointed out by *piotrekg2* what we need to do is

- create an array `prefix` which is the prefix sum of the array.
- Sort the `prefix` array, and we need to remember the index of the prefix array.
- Iterate through the prefix array, storing the minimum index we meet so far, the maximum different between the index is the answer.

**Note:** when we comparing value in `prefix`, if two indexes have **equivalent values**, so which has **smaller index** will be considered **larger**, this will avoid the case when the sum is 0.

Pseudo code:

```
  class Node{
      int val, index;
  }


  Node[]prefix = new Node[n];
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      prefix[i] = new Node(data[i],i);
      if(i - 1 >= 1)
        prefix[i].val += prefix[i - 1].val; 

  sort(prefix);
  int min = prefix[1].index;
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = 2; i <= n; i ++)
      if(prefix[i].index > min) 
         result = max(prefix[i].index - min + 1, result)
      min = min(min, prefix[i].index);
```

Comment: The subsequence must be continuous.

Comment: @dubov94 this doesn't matter, when you can skip any number, there is no reason you cannot choose your subset.

Comment: @PhamTrung The OP has contradicted this in the comments. I suspect that he's looking for a substring.

Comment: @PhamTrung I believe the edit was made before the comment. But we will just have to wait for the OP to return to be sure.

Comment: @dubov94 seems like I need a little bit of background here, when is he edit the question before or after his comment?

Comment: @dubov94 , reread my answer, the binary search is not to search for something **in** the array, but searching for the **length**, I still need to run through all indexes in my `prefix` array :)

Comment: @PhamTrung In general binary searching requires the elements from some total order. I think your algorithm silently assumes the following fact: if there is a substring with length `n` and sum > 0 then for all `m < n` there is a substring with length `m` and sum greater than 0. This fact does not hold for any input. Consider the following string: `5 -6 3 -6 5`. I think your algorithm will output 1 but the correct answer is 5 (the whole string).

Comment: @piotrekg2 hmm, you are right, thank you :(, will need to fix this.

Comment: @piotrekg2 updated my answer, proposed a new algorithm, this should be correct now :)